# layout with flex/div and @media

Tags: html, css, layout, flexbox

Welcome!

I want create my first responsive layout , I'm using divs combined with HTML5 new tags.

If browser window are more than 750px , it looks like I imagined it.
I used display: flex , direction - row. I think it's ok.

Problem is on less than 750px width - black color is new background color for container when its less than 750px , but why is article don't go after header? Then my layout I think should be ok.

Did I use "order" correct? I can't setup layout other way.

I would be grateful for any tips , what I can do about it - any sort of even negative rate of my code should be useful - I'm new and I think I'm the biggest noob in IT history but I try.

```css
body
{
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 font-size: 20px;
}
#container
{
 padding: 5em;
 margin: 2em;
 background-color: blue;

}

.clear
{
 clear:both;
}

#logo
{
 background-color: orange;
 float:left;
 width: 20%;
 height: 10em;
}
#header
{
 background-color: pink;
 float: left;
 width: 70%;
 height: 10em;
}
#nav
{
 background-color: lightgreen;

 float:left;
 width: 20%;
 height: 30em;

}
#article
{
 background-color: green;
 float:left;
 width: 70%;
 height: 30em;

 
}
#reklamy
{
 background-color: teal;
width: 10%;
float: right;
height: 40em;



}
#footer
{
 background-color: violet;
 height: 1em;
 width: 100%;

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 57em)
{
 body 
 {
  background-color: gold;
 }
 #container
 {
  
  padding: 0em;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
  background-color: black;

   

 }
 #logo
 {
  width: 30%;
  height: 10em;
  float:left;
  order:1;
 
 }
 #header
 {
  width: 90%;
  clear:both;
  order:3;
  height: 5em;
 }
 #footer
 {
  
  width: 100%;
  height: 10em;
  order:6;
 
 }
 #nav
 {
  width: 70%;
  float:left;
  height: 10em;
  order:2;
 }
 #article
 {
  
  width: 90%;
  height: 20em;
  float:left;
  order:5;

 }
 #reklamy
 {
  
  width: 10%;
  height: 26em;
  float: right;
  order:4;
  
 }
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="pl">
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>asd</title>
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/normalize.css"> 
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="logo">logo</div>
   <header id="header">tytuł artykułu</header>
   <div id="reklamy">reklamy lub wigety</div> 
   <div id="nav">nawigacja</div>
   <article id="article">artykuł</article>
   <div class="clear"></div>
   <footer id="footer">stopka</footer>
 </div>
  
  
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean "why is article don't go after header?" How do you want your layout to look less than 750 px? because i found the question unclear.

Comment: yes maybe i add image http://iv.pl/images/21332881245202260093.png

Comment: The code snippet is different from the picture you send. You have no header in your code just like the picture.

Comment: In snippet - more than 750 px , in pictrure it's change to responsive layout :)